# Vector of matrices in Julia

Tags: julia

How can I make a vector of (non-sparse) matrices in Julia? Then I want to use push! to add elements to that.

So if the name of the vector is V, then V[1] will be a matrix or Array{Float64,2}.

I know this works if the elements of the vector are sparse:
V = Array(SparseMatrixCSC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Matrix` alias (`Array{T, 2}`):

```rb
julia> v = Matrix{Float64}[]
0-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}

julia> x = rand(2, 2)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0877254  0.256971
 0.719441   0.653947

julia> push!(v, x)
1-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}:
 [0.0877254 0.256971; 0.719441 0.653947]

julia> v[1]
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0877254  0.256971
 0.719441   0.653947
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this and it worked:

V = Array(Array{Float64,2}, 0);

edit: As @pkofod suggested, this way is prefered:
T = Array{Float64,2};
V = Array{T}(0)

other options: V = Array{Float64,2}[ ] or V = Matrix{Float64}[ ]

Comment: Hi! If this answered your question, please click the green checkmark so the question is shows up as answered. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I tried that when I posted my answer, but the page told me I need to wait 2 days for accepting my own answer. If you meant I do it after 2 days, sure I will. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: If you want to do it like this, do note that `Array(T, n)` is sort of deprecated. I say sort of because the documentation says that it is, but I think there's still a discussion going on. The docs recommends `Array{T}(n)`. In your case `T = Array{Float64, 2}` or `T= Matrix{Float64}`.